# Convert Object into XML String

Tags: xml, string, web-services, object, windows-store-apps

I'm building a windows store app and I need to convert an object into a xml string, in order to send it via web service, where it will be reassembled as a PDF.

The object consists of 2 strings (name and ID) and a byte array, containing a photo (captured into a storagefile which then I convert into a byte array).

The problem is I'm not finding any way to convert this object into a valid xml string.

This is what I came up with from what I googled so far, but I'm not sure if it's what I need:

```
 Public Shared Function XmlFromObject(ByVal objTemp As Object, ByVal ID As String, ByVal name As String) As Task(of String)
            Dim IDName As String = ID + "_" + name + ".xml"
            Dim objStreamWriter As New StreamWriter(IDName)
            Dim x As New XmlSerializer(objTemp.GetType)
            using objStreamWriter                   
                x.Serialize(objStreamWriter, objTemp)
            end using
            Return IDName
End Function
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this one maybe it helps you to serialize your object:

I hope C# is also ok for you.

**C# Extension method:**

```
    public static string SerializeXml(this object instance)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(instance.GetType());
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, instance);
            stream.Position = 0;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var result = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>";
                result += reader.ReadToEnd();
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Your Object:**

```
class Dto
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get;set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var instance = new Dto();
instance.Id = "1";
instance.Name = "Any Name";
instance.Data = new byte[128];

var objAsString = instance.SerializeXml();
```

*Is this what you are searching for?*